# Xpath importxml google spreadheet

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm tryng to do web scraping by **importXML** in **Google Spreadsheet**, reading the content in this page:

> http://ddp.usach.cl/procesos-de-seleccion-internos

What I need to do is select the list below "Lista de Procesos, and separate it by rows. I went to the page, inspected and copy the XPath

```
//*[@id="node-page-442"]/div[1]/div/div/div/p[5]
```

Resulting in this code:

```
=importxml("http://ddp.usach.cl/node/442";"//*[@id='node-page-442']/div[1]/div/div/div/p[7]/text()")
```

However, when I try to load it I get an error #N/A

> "Imported content is empty"

Comment: I only want this:

Lista de Procesos:
SECRETARIO(A) A (DECANATO)
Cargo: Administrativo, Grado 13.
Lugar: Facultad Tecnológica
Proceso de selección: Interno
Fecha de postulación: Del  17 de Julio del 2018 al 20 de Julio del 2018. 
Ver más.
...

Everything by row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One path to get the nodes following the `h4` element with the content "Lista de Procesos" is

```
//article[@id='node-page-442']/div[contains(@class, 'content')]/div[contains(@class, 'field-name-body')]/div[@class='field-items']/div[contains(@class,'field-item')]/h4[contains(text(), 'Lista de Procesos')]/following-sibling::*
```

The retrieved children are not structured, but complete. If you can use XSLT-2.0, you could structure them by using `for-each-group` with `group-starting-with='strong'`. But this is only one possibility.

---

The expression could be reduced to the simple term:

```
//h4[contains(text(),'Lista de Procesos')]/following-sibling::*
```

Maybe this suits your needs better.